# jQuery toggle on PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, foreach

Using codeigniter 3.x

i'm trying to get data from database using foreach loop.

```
<h3 style="margin-right:15px;" id='hideshow'>August 2016</h3>
<?php foreach($duxeos as $e): ?>
<div class='content' ><h4 class="dropdate"><?php echo $e->fulldate;?></h4><div class="cdropdate" class="defhide"><?php echo $e->content;?></div></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

javascript :

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.hideshow').live('click', function(event) {
           jQuery('.content').toggle('show');
      });
  });

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.dropdate').live('click', function(event) {
           jQuery('.cdropdate').toggle('show');
      });
  });
```

now it's working, but when i press the hide button, it hide all content, how can i hide content that i want ?

Comment: I do not see any `loop` in your code.. Also not that, [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: `foreach($data as $e)` is foreach loop

Comment: All right! Consider second point in my comment..

Comment: yeah i know that, if it didn't allow multiple elements in same id, then how can it change the id value on every loop ?

Comment: Consider using `class` instead of `id`, it will make your life easy..

Comment: ok, now i'm using `class` , but when i press the `hide` button, it will hide all the content, can this just hide the content that i want ?

Comment: That is because you are not using `this` context inside handler-function... Do share updated code..

Comment: and how to use `this` context ? can you please add the code that using `this` context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `this` context in `handler-function`
- Use `.on` instead of `.live`
- Use `.closest` to get the closest element in order to find child of it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.dropdate').on('click', function(event) {
    jQuery(this).closest('.content').find('.cdropdate').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 style="margin-right:15px;" id='hideshow'>August 2016</h3>
<div class='content'>
  <h4 class="dropdate">Full-Date</h4>
  <div class="cdropdate defhide">Content</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='content'>
  <h4 class="dropdate">Full-Date</h4>
  <div class="cdropdate defhide">Content</div>
</div>
```